# Is it true that webpack wraps each module with function?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I was learning the inner workings of Webpack and tried to find out how the webpack ensures that there is no collision of variables or functions among modules. Then, found out this article [The article](https://dev.to/tanhauhau/what-is-module-bundler-and-how-does-it-work-3gp2) saying that Webpack uses a function to wrap each module to solve global scope issue. Is that true?

Comment: This doesnt seem to be a coding question. Its open ended and subject to opinion. Possibly just read the docs on webpack?

Comment: I don't use webpack anymore, and I use my own bundler system, and thats how I do it.  Basically I just wrap the function with module, exports, require sent as params..